# Primefaces Calendar component & date conversions

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces' calendar component. I have a corresponding string in VO. While saving in database, I need to convert the string to java.sql.date.

**xhtml**:

```
<p:calendar value="#{articlePromo.startDate}"
    id="vendorStartDateInputTxt" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mode="popup" showOn="button">
    <f:convertDateTime type="date"  dateStyle="short" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

The startDate (String) has the value : Sat Apr 21 05:30:00 IST 2012

**Java method to get sql Date**

```
public static Date getSQLDate(String strDate) {
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        java.util.Date dt = formatter.parse(strDate);
        sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sqlDate;
}
```

While converting java.util.date of calendar, I used the pattern dd/MM/yyyy. But the date it got converted to is: Sat Apr 21 05:30:00 IST 2012.

1. Is anything incorrect with **f:convertDateTime** tag written above.
2. If not, how can I convert this string to sql date. Not able to understand what format should be given.

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: try without the <f:convertDateTime at all and use  java.util.Date for articlePromo.startDate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `f:convertDateTime` only converts *String* to *Object* and vice versa. The *Object* for the `p:calendar` needs to be a `java.util.Date` (it is the `value` attribute). The *String* is the formatted date that you see in the browser!

The Primefaces calendar automatically attaches a converter. That's why you have the `pattern` attribute in `p:calendar`.

So you should remove your additional `f:convertDateTime` as already proposed by Daniel.

Then the conversion from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` is quite simple:

```java
public java.sql.Date sqlDate(java.util.Date calendarDate) {
  return new java.sql.Date(calendarDate.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

try

```
<p:calendar value="#{articlePromo.startDate}"
    id="vendorStartDateInputTxt" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mode="popup" showOn="button">
</p:calendar>
```

where `startDate` is `java.util.Date` object

Also, if you want to format the Date Object you can use the SimpleDateFormat :

```
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String s=df.format(startDate);
```